# Oracle Date Literal [DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM]

Tags: java, oracle, date, timestamp, nls

I'm trying to use the timestamp format [DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM] to insert my date.

I can't modify the database settings in anyway possible, and I have to insert the date through a JAVA's string format (I can't modify the class that defined it either).

Having said that, I need to literally reconstruct the format string-by-string without tempering the other class/db.

The nls settings for date is DD-MON-RR. 12-JUN-2012 and 12/JUN/2012 worked perfectly fine.

But I find it difficult to recreate the timestamp part of the date.

Listed below is a few format I've tried.

```
'12-JAN-12' < success
'12/JAN/2012' < success
'12/JAN/2012 10.30.25.000 AM < failed
'12/JAN/2012 10:30:25.000 AM < failed
```

Did messed up the : or .? Or was the zero(s) aren't enough for miliseconds? Been in this trouble for hours now.

Thanks in advance.

```
EDIT
```

After a few reasoning sessions, the seniors gave their permission to alter the model class. Everything's good now. Thanks for the help and suggestions.

Comment: What is the type of the field in the DB ? is it `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` ?

Comment: It was setted on `DATE`, but the available data seems are in `DD-MM-YYYY HH:Mi:ss AM` (e.g: `1/4/2010 4:52:46 PM`)

Comment: A date in oracle contains also time but only with seconds (no milliseconds). The format your trying requires a timestamp datatype

Comment: I have tried inserting this via SQL `12/JAN/2012 12:35:00 AM`. Didn't work either.

This error `ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string` pops up.

Comment: If you can use sql, why not do `to_date('12/01/2012 12:35:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM')` ? Instead of relying on NLS_DATE_FORMAT, which BTW, can you show it to us

Comment: I'm afraid I can't. The SQL are in the model class a senior make, and it seems he never bother to change the specific attribute into a DATE type. I can't change the SQL used nor the database settings.  Column in database - `DATE`.  Attribute in Model class - `String`.  I believe the class must be change for the model to correctly execute the statement.  I need to convert the Date into String for the model to use it. For now, I'm sticking with the literal syntax (DD-MMM-YYYY), without the timestamp (default to all zeros).

Comment: Before you give up, what is the nls_date_formt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you must send a string to the DB, you must rely on the implicit conversion of the oracle DB to the DATE type.
Since you can't change the DB settings, the only thing I can suggest is changing the session settings.
So, if you can run commands against the DB, try:

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
st.execute("alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'");
```

(or some other format (it's not recomended to use `mon` in your format because it might involve `NLS_TERRITORY` too))